# Firebase dynamic link option amv

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I created Manually Dynamic Link URL as below

https://uatandroidbetaprogram.page.link/?link=https://*******.com?YourDomain%3Dwww%26OrgID%3Dorgtest%26UserWelcomeName%3DJay%26UserAccountName%3Dr*****@*****.com&apn=*********&amv=10&afl=https://play.google.com/apps/testing/******************

1) In above url I use amv=10. my expectation is if old version app install on phone and if I click the above link it should upgrade the app. But it will just open the app

2) What is the use of amv and how to use it?

3) If old app installed on phone and I open google play store and try to update that time also it will open the app not update the app

Please provide me some solution

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the debug view (&d=1 on the link) you can see there are a few warnings which may be preventing the behavior:

https://uatandroidbetaprogram.page.link/?link=https://***************.com?YourDomain%3Dwww%26OrgID%3Dorgtest%26UserWelcomeName%3DJay%26UserAccountName%3Dr********&apn=****************&amv=10&afl=https://play.google.com/apps/testing/***************************&d=1

What you describe is the intended usage of amv, so it should work as you're expecting. Make sure it matches the versionCode parameter in your AndroidManifest.